# .htaccess Redirect Old Threads

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have moved to mybb to vanilla and want to redirect old threads to the new format, so the indexed threads on Google aren't lost.

The old format is

```
showthread.php?tid=3003
```

Whereas the new format is

```
index.php?p=/discussion/3003
```

How would I redirect this via `.htaccess`?

Comment: Why is the new format `index.php?p=/discussion/3003`? Because `/discussion/3003` is much nicer than `index.php?p=/discussion/3003`.

Comment: I agree, thats what the new software has, would i be able to change it to /discussion/3003  ?

Comment: Yes. Ask it as a separate question though: How do I change `index.php?p=/discussion/3003` to `/discussion/3003` with .htaccess?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use a 301 redirect (permanently moved) so that google will update its indexes with the new URLS, as users are redirected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule showthread.php index.php?p=/discussion/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Also, for your follow up, yes, you would update the rule above to just redirect to the "clean" url, and then use a silent rewruite to ivoke index.php...http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=2#not-so-simple

Comment: For some reason with this rewrite it redirects to mysite.com/home/mysite/public_html/index.php?p=/discussion/3003

Comment: add                         rewritebase /